# Component Test angular2-meteor

Tags: angular, meteor, mocha.js, angular2-meteor

I use [angular-meteor](https://github.com/urigo/angular-meteor/) to create a web app, but I try to write some test functions to test the app. When I use the command `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha`, it doesn't run any test files, 0 failures.

[image: Test Result]

Does anybody know how to set it up and test both client?

Answer (score 0):

First the files should be named *.test[s].[js|ts]. Secondly the files should not be placed in a folder named /tests, since these files are not automaticly picked up.

See https://guide.meteor.com/testing.html for more.